# Exporting cordova jar for Android

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant

I have been trying to follow the direction in here to get the jar.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html

So far here is the error I have been getting.

Buildfile: /Users/Thays/Source/corAPK/node_modules/cordova-android/framework/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/Thays/Source/corAPK/node_modules/cordova-android/framework/build.xml:42: You need to create the file 'local.properties' by running 'android update project -p .' here.

Move on and tried to run the required command more errors

---

The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

---

Invalid or unsupported command "update project -p ."

I move on and open it in android studio open up the file there let it do the work.

Ran ant again.
got 
BUILD FAILED
/Users/Thays/Source/corAPK/node_modules/cordova-android/framework/build.xml:124: Cannot find /Users/thays/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /Users/Thays/Source/corAPK/node_modules/cordova-android/framework/build.xml

Any help would great.